# How can i replace every emoji in a string with their unicode in java?

Tags: java, unicode, emoji

I have a string like this:

```
"\"title\":\"TEST title value \",\"text\":\" TEST text value.\"" ...
```

and i want to replace every emoji symbol with their unicode value like so:

```
"\"title\":\"U+1F47ATEST title value U+1F601\",\"text\":\"U+1F496 TEST text value.\"" ...
```

After searching a lot on the web, I found a way to "translate" one symbol to their unicode with this code:

```
String s = "";
int emoji = Character.codePointAt(s, 0); 
String unumber = "U+" + Integer.toHexString(emoji).toUpperCase();
```

But now how can i change my code to get all emoji in a string?

P.s. it can either be \Uxxxxx or U+xxxxx format

Comment: What if your actual text contained the simple plain text string U+12345? Or can you guarantee that's never going to happen?

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution:

```
String s = "your string with emoji";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  if (Character.isSurrogate(s.charAt(i))) {
    Integer res = Character.codePointAt(s, i);
    i++;
    sb.append("U+" + Integer.toHexString(res).toUpperCase());
  } else {
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
  }
}

//result
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Yes, but other surrogate chars may lead to the same problem. In case we have the only emojis as specific characters the solution will handle that properly.

Comment: There is no "problem" here. He wants to replace emojis with their unicode refs. And as far as I can tell - just emojis, not every "unusual" char.

Comment: I tried to copy this code but i get the error: 'The method isSurrogate(char) is undefined for the type Character', how can i fix it?

Comment: Try to import java.lang.Character; Do you have such a class?

Comment: Didn't have it, but even after adding it I still get the same exact problem. The solution from AterLux works tho

Comment: Seems that you are using version java 6 or less. In this case you could create privete method and use it: public static boolean isSurrogate(char ch) {
    return ch >= '\ud800' && ch < '\ue000';
  }

Comment: Then the next problem would be that Java 6 had no Character.codePointAt method either.

Answer (score 1):

Emoji are scattered among different [unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block). For example (0x1F47A) and (0x1F496) are from [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs), while (0x1F601) is from [Emoticons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block))

If you want to filter out symbols you need to decide what unicode blocks (or their range) you want to use. For example:

```java
    String s = "\"title\":\"TEST title value \",\"text\":\" TEST text value.\"";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, l = s.length() ; i < l ; i++) {
      char ch = s.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)) {
        i++;
        char ch2 = s.charAt(i); // Load low surrogate
        int codePoint = Character.toCodePoint(ch, ch2);
        if ((codePoint >= 0x1F300) && (codePoint <= 0x1F64F)) { // Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs + Emoticons
          sb.append("U+").append(Integer.toHexString(codePoint).toUpperCase());
        } else { // otherwise just add characters as is
          sb.append(ch);
          sb.append(ch2);
        }
      } else { // if not a surrogate, just add the character
        sb.append(ch);
      }
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(result); // "title":"U+1F47ATEST title value U+1F601","text":"U+1F496 TEST text value."
```

To get only emojis you can narrow the condition using, for example, [this list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

But if you want to escape any surrogate symbol, you can get rid of `codePoint` check inside the code

Comment: From what I know about all this, there's no single range in any given unicode plane that contains all emojis and doesn't intersect with actual letters. So the range from your answer is not correct, and only correct way to check is to download and use unicode-emoji file.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes. That was just an example.

Comment: It works great, but i'm not sure what unicode blocks I will recive, can I swap 0x1F300 and 0x1F64F with the first and last unicode block? If yes where can I find them?

Comment: @BladeITA, you can look here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/ - these are all block there are in standard today, you will need to find ones you'd like to replace. Note that "normal" range also has emoji-like chars, in "Dingbats" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't need to specify any code point ranges, nor do you need to worry about surrogates. Instead, just specify the Unicode blocks for which you want characters to be presented as Unicode escapes. This is achieved by using the field declarations in the [`Character.UnicodeBlock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) class. For example, to determine whether (0x1F601) is an emoticon:

```
boolean emoticon = Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of("".codePointAt(0)));
System.out.println("Is  an emoticon? " + emoticon); // Prints true.
```

Here's general purpose code. It will process any `String`, presenting individual characters as their Unicode equivalents if they are defined within the specified Unicode code blocks:

```
package symbolstounicode;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SymbolsToUnicode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Character.UnicodeBlock[] blocksToConvert = new Character.UnicodeBlock[]{
            Character.UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS, 
            Character.UnicodeBlock.MISCELLANEOUS_SYMBOLS_AND_PICTOGRAPHS};
        String input = "\"title\":\"TEST title value \",\"text\":\" TEST text value.\"";
        String output = SymbolsToUnicode.toUnicode(input, blocksToConvert);

        System.out.println("String to convert: " + input);
        System.out.println("Converted string: " + output);
        assert ("\"title\":\"U+1F47ATEST title value U+1F601\",\"text\":\"U+1F496 TEST text value.\"".equals(output));
    }

    // Converts characters in the supplied string found in the specified list of UnicodeBlocks to their Unicode equivalents.
    static String toUnicode(String s, final Character.UnicodeBlock[] blocks) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        List<Integer> cpList = s.codePoints().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        cpList.forEach(cp -> sb.append(SymbolsToUnicode.inCodeBlock(cp, blocks) ? 
                "U+" + Integer.toHexString(cp).toUpperCase() : Character.toString(cp)));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // Returns true if the supplied code point is within one of the specified UnicodeBlocks.
    static boolean inCodeBlock(final int cp, final Character.UnicodeBlock[] blocksToConvert) {

        for (Character.UnicodeBlock b : blocksToConvert) {
            if (b.equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(cp))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's the output, using the test data in the OP:

```
run:
String to convert: "title":"TEST title value ","text":" TEST text value."
Converted string: "title":"U+1F47ATEST title value U+1F601","text":"U+1F496 TEST text value."
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Notes:

- I used font *Segoe UI Symbol* for the code and the output window to render the symbols properly.
- The basic idea in the code is:

  - First, specify the `String` to be converted, and the Unicode code blocks for which characters should be converted to Unicode.
  - Next, convert the `String` into a set of code points using `String.codePoints()`, and store them in a `List`.
  - Finally, for each code point, determine whether it exists within any of the specified Unicode blocks, and convert it if necessary.